# TestFlight - Invitation already redeemed

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm new to TestFlight and frustrated. I have a couple users whom I have added to iTunes Connect Users for the app we are testing. They receive the invite and when the launch it, the get an error stating that the invitation has already been redeemed. I've removed their user accounts from iTunes Connect Users and readded...same result. I've removed them from iTunes Connect altogether then readded them and *then* added them to iTunes Connect Users. They still get "invitation already redeemed" when they click on the link in the invite. Can it really be this difficult to get users access to TestFlight builds?

Answer (score -2):

I've written a thorough guide in testing apps via TestFlight here: https://github.com/glennposadas/TestFlight-Guide/wiki/A-Thorough-Guide-In-Testing-Apps-Via-TestFlight---For-Clients,-Bosses,-and-Testers

The key is make sure the team gets the email. That email from TestFlight has the button or link to get started with testing.

Comment: I'll read over your write up. Many thanks. But that's part of the problem. The user does get the email, and when they click on the button they get the error that the invitation has already been redeemed.